# PHP - fgetcsv - quote marks are lost from input in UTF-8 encoded web app

Tags: php, cakephp, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to import data from CSV files into a web app that uses utf-8 encoding.  I'm using fgetcsv (I don't have to if there's a better way).  I'm using utf8_encode to attempt to translate characters from whatever the file's encoding is.  When I call mb_check_encoding on strings that come out of this particular file, I get 'ASCII'.

There are a few strange characters in the input.  utf8_encode deals happily with é characters (where before they were coming out as black diamond question marks).  However, it fails to translate double quotes and apostrophes, and instead just removes them.

Help much appreciated, thanks.  I'm using CakePHP, in case that gives me some more options!

Edit - I meant utf8_encode, not utf8_decode.

Comment: If your app uses UTF-8 why are you converting the text to latin1 (that's what utf8_decode does)?

Comment: There's no magic function to deal with encodings! You need to *know* what encoding your input is in and convert it appropriately into your preferred encoding. Automagic charset detection and conversion simply does not work.

Comment: So, what *is* the encoding of your input?

Comment: Oops, I meant utf8_encode.  Edited my question.  Input files are all in the same format (they are produced by a single person), as mentioned mb_check_encoding gives 'ASCII' when I try to find out the encoding of the file.  Thanks!

Comment: The result of automatic charset detection doesn't necessarily mean a lot. Figure out the encoding of the file yourself. Ask the creator. Look at his editor settings. Open the data file in a browser or editor and keep changing the encoding setting until the text looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one call to [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) with the correct charset for the `$in_charset` parameter.

```
$utf8Text = iconv($inputCharset, 'UTF-8', $text);
```

You need to *know* the input charset. There's no way around it. Make a specification that all input needs to be in ISO-8859-1, or whatever you prefer. Alternatively, find out what the charset of your input is (ask the author, test yourself in an editor, whatever). Alternatively, require that the input needs to specify what encoding it's in somewhere, somehow.

Encoding is not black magic. You just need to be aware of what encoding some text is in and what encoding you want it to be in. Then use a function like `iconv` that can cleanly translate the characters from one encoding to another. `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` translate between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8. Their names are chosen terribly, since they suggest they can automagically translate anything from and to UTF-8, but that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks.  This has cleared things up for me.  I kinda assumed that utf8_encode would just take anything and return utf8 output (like you said).  I'm now using iconv('Windows-1252','UTF-8',$text) and all of the characters are now being dealt with properly.

Comment: @Will Glad you saw the light. :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the problem of strange characters by using the function below:

```
function htmlallentities($str){
  $res = '';
  $strlen = strlen($str);
  for($i=0; $i<$strlen; $i++){
    $byte = ord($str[$i]);
    if($byte < 128) // 1-byte char
      $res .= $str[$i];
    elseif($byte < 192); // invalid utf8
    elseif($byte < 224) // 2-byte char
      $res .= '&#'.((63&$byte)*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
    elseif($byte < 240) // 3-byte char
      $res .= '&#'.((15&$byte)*4096 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
    elseif($byte < 248) // 4-byte char
      $res .= '&#'.((15&$byte)*262144 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*4096 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
  }
  return $res;
```

For example, for apostrophe (') i used the following code snippet:

```
$value = "Whatâ€™s your name?";
$value = htmlallentities(utf8_decode($value));
$str = "&#12287;";
$str2 = "'";
$value = str_replace($str, $str2, $value);
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

Will be glad if those help you.

Comment: Can you specify what this code does exactly? Just posting code that does *something* regarding charsets without specifying what it should do isn't very helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This worked with one change - htmlallentities(utf8_decode($value)); changed to htmlallentities(utf8_encode($value));.  I didn't need the str_replace code to get it to work.  Great, thanks!

Comment: when curly apostrophes are being rendered as "â€tm", then i used the given function to solve the problem. I just gave him one type of solution as he can solve his problem similar way. I thought that it may help him.

Comment: @Will This code is attempting to fix [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). If you have mojibake, you have already failed. You have failed because you interpreted some text with an incorrect charset. The solution is **not** to fix the broken text, it's to interpret the original with the correct charset and cleanly convert it if needed. For that you need to know the original charset. Conversion is entirely [straight forward](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) and requires no guessing or manual trickery, you only need to *know* the original encoding.